# How to wait for a SmsQuery from a phone number before action

Tags: sms, flutter

I'm trying to trigger an action after receiving a text message, without success.  I can launch my action when an SMS is sent and even delivered, but not when receiving one. I'm using sms 0.1.0 https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sms#-readme-tab-

to be clear

1  - I can send an sms to another device

2  - the other device receives the sms

3  - the other device then sends me an sms

4 -  I'd like to trigger an action on receipt of this reply

Currently, I can't find how to do that

here is the current code

...

```
 SmsSender sender = new SmsSender();
 String _nirbinumber;
 SmsReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver();
 SmsMessage _lastMessage = new SmsMessage(null, "No new messages");
```

...

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
                height: 250.0,
                child: new Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Center(
                      child :
                       new Container(
                        child : new FloatingActionButton(
                            child : new Icon (Icons.location_on),

                            onPressed: ()
                            async {

                               SmsMessage message = new SmsMessage(_nirbinumber, '$loc1');    
                               sender.sendSms(message);
                               message.addStateListener((state) {
                               if (state == SmsMessageState.Delivered) {
                                 receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) => _lastMessage = msg);

                                  setState(() {
                                    savegeoValue();    // function to extract GPS coordinate of the received sms and save it with "shared preference" 
                                    StreamSubscription<SmsMessage> _smsSubscription;
                                    }
                                  );
                                  showMap();   // function to launch googlemap view
                                 }
                                }
                              );
                            }
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
            )
          ],
        )
    )
);
```

}

Comment: Are you listening to the SmsReceiver.onSmsReceived stream? Could you post any code of what's working / not working?

Comment: @RichardHeap Yes, I will share my code after work, actually I use SMSreceived stream but the problem is : "SMSreceived stream" read the last sms received only when the sms is received by the device ( last upgrade of Sms pub ), so at this moment I read the previous sms and not the requested sms because the sms isn't arrived yet. So I have a shift, I have always the previous sms read. thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are always one message 'behind' is this line `receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) => _lastMessage = msg);`

This line just creates the listener. It *doesn't* wait for the arrival of a message, so you continue immediately into setState (with the previous message still in `_lastMessage`). In fact, it makes no sense to keep creating the listener - you just need one.

I'd structure it differently so that you always have the same listener, which tells you about all incoming messages, and you look for the replies based on, for example, phone number, or some expected characters in the body.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _nirbinumber = '12345';
  // _lastMessage is probably redundant, as you can use msg (below)
  SmsMessage _lastMessage = new SmsMessage('', '');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // listen to the stream of *all* message arriving
    new SmsReceiver().onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) {
      // filter out the replies by number
      if (msg.address == _nirbinumber) {
        // fantastique - it's one of the ones we want
        setState(() {
          _lastMessage = msg;
        });
        saveGeoValue(msg); // this cannot use the value in _lastMessage as it will not have been set yet
        showMap(msg);
      }
    });
  }

  void _send() {
    // fire (and forget)
    new SmsSender().sendSms(new SmsMessage(_nirbinumber, 'test message'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('SMS demo'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text(_lastMessage.body),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _send,
        tooltip: 'Send SMS',
        child: new Icon(Icons.sms),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```